# How to determine that data previously unmarshalled with JAXB was changed?

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I only want to marshall the data with JAXB to a file if the previously unmarshalled data has been changed by the user. I know that classes generated by JAXB don't have `equals()` method. Is there any simple way to determine whether the data has been changed after unmarshalling?

E.g. `org.w3c.dom.Document` has `isEqualNode()` method for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to marshal to a org.w3c.dom.Document and to use its isEqualNode()-method. If the original document differs from the new one then I marshal to a file. As I haven't so much XML data it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

So, JAXB does not produce classes it marshalls data from instances of classes or populates instances by unmarshalling xml. Usually the classes are generated prior to compile-time by XJC. One option is to update the classes to include an equals method. This is not a great idea since you generally don't want to update generated code in case you need to regenerate at a later date. So you could write a utility class that takes two instances of the classes and compares them.

This is for comparing after unmarshalling. Another option would be to perform a check prior to unmarshalling by doing a checksum on the file.

Answer (score 0):

The best is probably to implement Comparator or utility classes to check equality.
You could for instance rely on commons-lang [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) and [CompareToBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html).

Comment: I couldn't understand the advantages of using the EqualsBuilder. You have to write some code in each of the classes you are interested in, haven't you? Doesn't Eclipse do it better with "Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals()..."?

Comment: Have you seen the reflectionEquals method? With Eclipse (the process is usefull but if you class changes, you have to regenerate hashCode and Equals). With reflectionEquals, you won't have to change your code when you add a new field or remove another one.

Comment: Moreover, generate hashCode and equals enduce to modify the generated classes (which is not good, since you will have to do this each time you regenerate the code). Using EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals let you write a utility class instead.

Answer (score 0):

One fairly standard approach is to add a `transient boolean` to the class, `isDirty`, and your setter methods will set that to true.  (or, if you prefer, add a `dateModified`)

Obviously, this requires changing your internal class code which may be inappropriate.

You could also keep some `Set` of all objects that have been modified.  But getting this logic correct may also be tricky or impossible depending on how your code is organized.

Comment: The advantage of "isDirty"-approach is that I don't have to keep a copy of the original data for later comparision. But at the other side I have to find all the places in the program where the data can change. Besides, a setter doesn't always change the value, it may set the previous value.

Comment: If you are lucky, the code uses setters for everything, in which case it's easy to add isDirty.  But, if not, yes, you have to root around a lot.  I like to change the names of the fields, or make them private, and have the compiler tell me what breaks.  In general, I would not bother being super-sophisticated about setting to the same value.  Unless this happens a lot, it will only cause a "little bit" of extra marshalling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JAXB2 Basics Plug-in to have equals methods generated into your model classes:

- http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/JAXB2+Basics+Plugins

Comment: Is there a plugin for Eclipse? I couldn't find anything. I'm too lazy to deal with Maven configuration etc.